# Input Field plus Submit Button cover full column width on one line/row in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve the following with Twitter Bootstrap:

I would like to have a simple `<input>` field and a simple `<button>` on one single line or row in Twitter Bootstrap. They should cover the entire width of the column/parent container (ie be of the same width as span12). I do not want to give the button a fixed with - I want the button to be fluid width (width determined by the button text). The input field should use the remaining space left of the button.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3202/

The fiddle shows the button aligned to the right.

**Now: how do I get the input field to extend to the very left edge of the parent container?**

I would like to retain the responsiveness, of course.

Any ideas? I do prefer a non Javascript based solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3251/

Using approach from here:

http://boulderinformationservices.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/input-field-and-submit-button-on-the-same-line-full-width/

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div style="width:100%;background-color:#d0d0d0;text-align:center;">Example of a Full row</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <form class="form-inline">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn" style="float:right;">Button</button>
                        <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .3em;">
                            <input style="height:1.6em;width:100%" type="text" placeholder="full width minus button width" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is it! Your bounty will be on its way as soon as its available for me to award you...

Comment: Thanks, this is my first bounty! Also just realized I misspelled class as ckass, corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the width of the button with jQuery, and get the width of the parent span12 then set the input width to be the difference of the two.
I don't think there is any other way if the button width has to be dynamic.

Comment: I should have added that using Javascript is not my preferred way of achieving my goal :-) but thank you! :-)